# Is there any FOSS tool to reliably create a UML model from existing c++ code?

Tags: c++, uml

I have tried Umbrello and ArgoUML; and both are unable to generate code from an existing c++ codebase. Though they have limited capabilities in these areas, they both fail spectacularly importing a file with std, boost, SDL and local includes. Is there anything in the FOSS world that will model reasonably complex c++ code. The UML part is optional, generating coherent and accurate visualizations of the code is what matters.

Note: Tools like gprof2dot as well as doxygen can process the source, but their output is so complex as to be equivalently difficult to grasp as the original code.

Note2: Since one cannot ask about tools on SO anymore, let me rephrase the question like this:

How, given a large, old, complex and crufty c++ code base, can one quickly and efficiently perform major refactorings. By major, I mean things like:

- extracting entire structs/enums/classes from an existing source/header pair into their own files
- adding/deleting namespaces
- changing function signatures
- etc.

Some things are approachable with grep and sed; however, discovering and managing include dependencies can be overwhelming. I'm currently stuck with the "change-and-fix" method -- try refactoring something and iteratively build and fix errors as the compiler point them out. For widely used objects, this is **slow**. What is the proper approach?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I used Doxygen for this on a couple of projects.

It wasn't great but it was better than starting from scratch.

Comment: I've tried that, and gprof+gprof2dot. They work well, but the output is as confusing as the source. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.142.5718&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper from 2005 describes the *pilfer* tool, which is now included within the [srctools](http://www.sdml.info/projects/srctools/) project. It's available under a GNU General Public License.

Comment: There is no sign of development in the last few years. Thanks, though.